# Get Test score through range values

Tags: c#, if-statement, dictionary, decimal

I have a requirement where I take an int (score in the example) below and return a decimal value by comparing it against various range conditions. If score is between 1 and 10 then the test is automatically failed and a decimal is not returned (in this case I return the string "FAILED". Higher than then 10 and the corresponding decimal value is returned based on what range score matches. This feels wrong doing it this way and was wondering if there is a better method. I considered using a dictionary with each range e.g. between 1 and 10 stored in a key and then querying this to return the value.  However, I'm unsure how to do this. Can anyone suggest a better method?

Thank you

```
public decimal GetTestScore(int score, out string status)
    {
        decimal score = 0m;
        string status = string.Empty;

        if(score >= 1 && score <= 10)
             status = FAILED;
        else if(score >= 10 && score <= 20)
            score = 1.0;
        else if(score >= 20 && score <= 30)
            score = 2.0;
        else if(score >= 30 && score <= 40)
            score = 3.0;
        return score;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you predict that your solution may have to expand to accommodate more score definitions, or have user configurable score definitions, you could use something like the following example:

```
public class ScoreResult
{
    public int Low { get; set; }
    public int High { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public double ReplacementScore { get; set; }

    public ScoreResult(int low, int high, string status, 
          double replacementScore)
    {
        Low = low;
        High = high;
        Status = status;
        ReplacementScore = replacementScore;
    }
}

public class ScoreCalculator
{
    private List<ScoreResult> _scores = new List<ScoreResult>();

    public ScoreCalculator()
    {
        /*These are easy to change and could be
          loaded from a database/service*/
        _scores.Add(new ScoreResult(1, 10, "FAILED", 0));
        _scores.Add(new ScoreResult(10, 20, string.Empty, 1));
        _scores.Add(new ScoreResult(20, 30, string.Empty, 2));
        _scores.Add(new ScoreResult(30, 40, string.Empty, 3));
    }

    public ScoreResult GetScoreResult(int score)
    {
        //Will return null if no match found
            return _scores.FirstOrDefault
                    (s => score >= s.Low && score <= s.High);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
    var result = GetScoreResult(9);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Status); //FAILED
    Console.WriteLine(result.ReplacementScore); //0.0
```

Each score can be represented by an instance of `ScoreResult`, this makes it very easy to find a match using Linq and very easy to add/remove/modify your scores.  You could even store the `ScoreResult` data in a database so that it is easily configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Well first return a nullable decimal and if validation failed, simply return null.

`public decimal? GetTestScore(int score)`

The other question is: why does it feel wrong? For simple application this will be enough.

Don't overengineer the problem.

A dictionary is not space efficient in your situation as you would need many redundant values for the ranges to map to one single score value.

Your solution is actually wrong as you are comparing to score <=20 and then for the next score value >=20 which is redundant (even if it behaves correctly)

Edit: You can of course simplify your check if the constraints are projectable

```
    public decimal? GetTestScore(int score)
    {

        if (score >= 1 && score <= 10)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (score < 1 || score > 40)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return (score-1) / 10;
    }
```

Edit again: Added boundary conditions

Comment: Nullable return type looks good. Should have considered this instead of returning a string as well as a decimal. To answer your other question I'm teaching myself TDD and this was part of a simple test to try and recreate a situation where I would be retrieving the test score from a database(but with not actually creating a database yet). Thank you for your response.

Comment: Be careful not to learn TDD the wrong way. TDD is not a way of problem solving. You should always think first on how to solve the problem. Do not start and hope that by TDD every complex scenario can be solved just on the go. TDD is Red Green Refactor, you may miss the refactor part here. Algorithms etc are for instance poorly solved with TDD (like implementing A* with TDD) since code tends to grow to cover edge cases which can be handled by the algorithm itself. Your sample code looks like it suffers exactly from that issue).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
public decimal GetTestScore(int score, out string status)
{
    status = string.Empty;

    if (score < 10)
    {
        status = "FAILED";

        return 0m;
    }

    return Math.Ceiling(score / 10m);
}
```